# Binary Search Tree: Search Function Issue

Tags: c++, search, root, binary-search-tree

My search function that I have implemented sort of works. When i search for a value that doesnt exist the search function works find and returns false. When i search for a value that is the root it works fine and returns true. The problem is when i search for a value other than the root that is in the tree already but it is returning false. Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

```
template <class Comparable>
bool BinarySearchTree<Comparable>::findValue(const Comparable& value){
if(root->element == value){
    return true;
}

if(value > root->element)
{
    if(root->right != NULL)
    {
        root->right->findValue(value);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
if(value < root->element)
{
    if(root->left != NULL)
    {
    root->left->findValue(value);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

These are my private data members, these cannot be altered in any way.

```
private:
struct BinaryNode
{
    Comparable element;
    BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *left;
    BinarySearchTree<Comparable> *right;
};
BinaryNode *root;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you `return false` from the right node, you well never even attempt the left node.

Try returning true instead;

```
if(value > root->element)
{
    if(root->right != NULL)
    {
        if(root->left->findValue(value))
        {  
            return true;
        }
    }
}
if(value < root->element)
{
    if(root->left != NULL)
    {
        if(root->left->findValue(value)
        {  
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false
```

Comment: I've tried what you said and i'm getting the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the result of `root->left->findValue(value);` and `root->right->findValue(value)`

Currently you are calling the findValue function for those nodes, but not storing the value or returning it anywhere so the result is being lost.

Comment: I've tried what you said, yet it still not working

Sorry, here is the edit with a proper pastebin http://pastebin.com/CQhAw7CF